# Как организовать пакетное добавление информации в базу данных MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Написал тяжелый скрипт, который получает информацию из XML файла, далее переходит по ссылке из файла и получает информацию с сайта на который перешел, возвращает полученную информацию в скрипт и сохраняет данные в базу MySQL.

В XML файле тысячи адресов с которых нужно получить дополнительную информация из-за чего я столкнулся с проблемой зависания скрипта не по причине нехватки памяти (причина мне не ясна, памяти достаточно свободной).

Из 6000 адресов, за пару часов скрипт добавляет в базу около 450 и останавливается.

Пожалуйста, помогите написать функцию, изменить скрипт таким образом, чтобы он отрабатывал все 6000 адресов не останавливаясь.

Я пробовал добавить `sleep(SLEEP);` но не смог корректно написать для этого функцию.

Код:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
require_once 'config.php';


/* Вариант 2. 2 строки ниже для вставки только новых значений(не заменяя старых) */
$Query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `xml`(`id_xml`,`date_xml`,`title_xml`,`link_xml`) VALUES";
$ODKU = ';';

$values = "";
$text = "";

function page_title($url){
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    // Clean up title: remove EOL and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;
}

// Получаем XML файл

$file = '/var/www/test.xml'; // сохраняем файл XML

$read = simplexml_load_file($file); // получаем объект класса из файла

$xml = $read->Category->Club;

$count = count($xml); // кол-во элементов массива




for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

$text = page_title('https://test.com='.$xml[$i]->Id.'');    

$date_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml[$i]->Id);
$title_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml[$i]->Title);
$id_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml[$i]->Description);
$link_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml[$i]->Title);


if (strlen($text) > 0) {
    $link_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
} else {
    $link_xml = mysql_real_escape_string($xml[$i]->Title);
}

//    sleep(SLEEP);

  $values .= "('$id_xml', '$date_xml','$title_xml','$link_xml'),";
  /* заносим данные в БД если накопилось 1000 записей при подготовке запроса */ 
  if($i % 1000 == 0)
  {
    $values[strlen($values)-1]=' ';
    $res = mysql_query("$Query $values $ODKU");
    $values = "";
  }

}


if(strlen($values)>0)
{
  $values[strlen($values)-1]=' ';
  /* заносим данные в БД */
  $res = mysql_query("$Query $values $ODKU");    
}

echo 'Done';
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Сложно помочь, не зная,  в чём проблема. Попробуйте отдебажить, добавив вывод какого-нибудь сообщения внутри цикла при каждой итерации. Кроме того, попробуйте запустить скрипт, начиная с приблизительно того места, на котором зависает.

Comment: Он не зависает, просто останавливается, но я попробую воспользоваться вашим советом. Если не запрашивать дополнительные данные по url, все 6000 записей добавляются в базу за 10 секунд без проблем.

Comment: Может это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting но из своего опыта скажу, что одной операцией загрузить 6000 страниц глупо. И лучше загружать курлом, так как там можно настроить все параметры, - таймауты, юзервгент, реферер и прочее. А так мало ли какой сайт попался, банящий вас как парсинг скрипт. Разбивайте задачу на 100 итераций..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php - лимит времени выполнения изменён?

также у хостеров могут быть своими лимиты - можно уточнить у поддержки.

самый простой вариант - не пытаться обработать весь файл сразу, а обрабатывать мелкие группы

Comment: max_execution_time = 0. У меня vps с 4 gb памяти. Вот я и хотел обрабатывать мелкие группы `sleep(SLEEP);`, как это сделать не понял.

Comment: Хотел обернуть парсер в функцию и вызывать ее каждый раз после сохранения результатов в базу, получил данные с одного url - сохранил и пошел дальше, как это сделать не разобрался.

Comment: как пример, если это страничка - `for($i = $_GET['offset']; $i < $_GET['amount']; $i++){` вместо `for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){` и запускаем скрипт аяксом, увеличивая offset на каждой итерации

Comment: а если это не страничка, а файл?